# чтение файла на php и обработка данных

Tags: php

Имеется текстовый файл в котором много строк, в каждой строке написано:

`дата добавления|ФИО|адрес человека|город|почтовый индек|номер телефона(где то и нет)|`

разделителем является прямая палочка как в примере
нужно на PHP прочитать этот файл, и отсортировать людей по городу проживания.
T.е. что-то в таком виде должно получится:

```
09.02.16|Станислав....|Москва|113623|+7.....91
07.02.16|Енакентий....|Москва|105173|+7.....92
09.03.16|Роман....|Москва|141411|+7.....93
11.04.16|Иван....|Москва|127204|+7.....94
29.05.16|Станислав....|Москва|143350|+7.....95
```

помогите пожалуйста реализовать код)

Comment: Обратитесь к фрилансерам. Тут помогают, а не решают проблемы за вас.

Comment: читаете файл в массив функцией `file()`, сортируете массив с помощью `usort()` используя в качестве функции сравнения свою функцию, которая делает explode строк и сравнивает нужное поле. пишите массив обратно в файл или выдаете куда вам нужно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Поддерживаю ArchDemon, но самому было интересно решить данную задачу.
Примите код, как подарок))

**P.S.** Хороший пост на данную тему [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2699086/sort-multi-dimensional-array-by-value).

> *Код - чисто костыль, он не практичен и предназначен сугубо для одноразового решения Вашей задачи.*

**Пример работает с версией PHP 5.2 и ниже**

```
$str = file('путь_до_файла_со_списком');

usort($str, 'sortByOrder'); // Сортируем

// Сама функция, где прописана логика сортировки
function sortByOrder($a, $b) {
    $expA = explode("|", $a); // Разбиваем строку на массив
    $expB = explode("|", $b); // тоже самое
    return $expA[2] > $expB[2];
}

// Тут просто печатаем отсортированный массив
foreach($str as $line) {
    echo $line.'<br />';
}
```

**Для версии PHP 5.3 и выше можем то же сделать с помощью безымянной функции**

```
usort($str, function($a, $b) {
    $expA = explode("|", $a);
    $expB = explode("|", $b);
    return $expA[2] > $expB[2];
});
```

Comment: ммм. Не забывайте скобочки ставить у `if` не дай бог вам такой код на поддержку.

Comment: Мне кажется, что $exp = explode(PHP_EOL, $str); будет немного правильнее

Comment: @Naumov "не дай бог..." какой части кода это касается?

Comment: @mix в данном случае `if` вообще не нужен. Приучайтесь лениться :) Пишите так `return $expA[2] > $expB[2];`

Comment: огромное спасибо!!! Дай Бог вам счастья)

Comment: @Venta нет не будетмы за ранее незнаем как сохранён код. Правильнее `file()` заюзать вместо `file_get_contents,explode` http://php.net/manual/ru/function.file.php.

Comment: @Naumov есть в этом смысл, спасибо!)

Comment: И да заместо `if()` стоит использовать `return strcmp()`